# How do I get all possible numbers that can be achieved by removing digits from an existing number?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to find all the possible numbers I can get by removing one or more digits from a certain number, but not reordering them (i.e. 1234 can become 124 or 134 or 12, but not 143).

I've tried this to find them:

```
                xdigits = list(map(int, str(x)))
                ydigits = list(map(int, str(y)))
                for m in xdigits:
                    if m in xdigits and m in ydigits:
                        xdigits.remove(m)
                        ydigits.remove(m)
                        numerator = int(''.join(str(i) for i in xdigits))
                        denominator = int(''.join(str(i) for i in ydigits))
                        try:
                            if (numerator/denominator) == (x/y)                             
                                print('Remove ' + str(removelist) + ': ' + str(x) + '/' + str(y) + ' equals ' + str(numerator) + '/' + str(denominator) )
                        except ZeroDivisionError:
                            pass
```

But this does not give me all the possible situations (i.e. when 134 and 124 are both possible answers, only 134 is outputted). How can I get all the possible values?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your code. What would be "x" and "y", for example?
Anyway, I believe this code should solve your problem. It basically creates all combinations of lists in which each element can be the digit for that position , or a empty string. After that it removes the first list (which would be all empty elements), then it joins the lists and converts it to integers.

```
import itertools

def list2num(x):
    return  int(''.join(x))

def get_digit_combinations(number):
    number_str = str(number)
    possibilities = [['',digit] for digit in number_str]
    list_of_digits = list(itertools.product(*possibilities))
    list_of_digits.pop(0) # removing first element, where the string is empty
    return [list2num(x) for x in list_of_digits]

all_numbers = get_digit_combinations(1234)
print(all_numbers)
print(len(all_numbers))
```

Let me know if that works.